# Securing local docker private registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to create a secure private Docker registry that would work only in the local network and be accessed by IP address.
I have read a lot of articles regarding this issue but most of them talk about the need to have a registered domain name that points to a valid public IP address ( where the registry is ) , and then obtaining a certificate for such domain.

I'd like to know if there's a way of creating a docker registry with the following properties:

- accessible only from the local network
- secured with a valid certificate ( not the self signed certificate which is still considered "insecure" by docker )

How would I obtain a valid certificate for such a registry? I understand that certificates cannot be created for IP addresses alone, but can I generate a certificate for a domain that is registered but doesn't point to any public IP ( I've read something about dns-01 challenge, so I belive it's possible )  and then use that certificate, provided I map the said domain to the local IP of the server in my hosts file.

If this isn't possible, what is the best alternative for creative a secure, local, private docker registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Nginx to secure your Docker Registry.

The relevant documentation is here:

https://github.com/docker/distribution/tree/master/contrib/compose

You can use self-signed certificates if you add the root CA to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates and run **update-ca-certificates** command on the clients.

Comment: This was the method I attempted but I forgot to update the ca-certificates. I found a solution at  [this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8849)